# Asymptotic behavior of solution to a nonlinear ode.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, asymptotics, stability-in-odes

If $x,y:\mathbb{R}_+\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are real analytic functions satisfying
$$2\dot{x}x-2\dot{y}y=y\dot{x}-x\dot{y}$$

over $\mathbb{R}_+$, where $\dot{x}$ means $\frac{d}{dt}x(t)$ and similar for $\dot{y}$. In addition, $x(t)y(t)\to 1$ as $t\to\infty$.

Is it possible that $x(t)$ or $y(t)$ is unbounded, i.e., there exists a sequence $(t_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $x(t_k)\to\infty$ or $y(t_k)\to\infty$ where  $t_k\to\infty$ as $k\to\infty$?

---

I know how to deal with it if the RHS of the displayed equation is $0$, i.e.,
$$2\dot{x}x-2\dot{y}y=0$$
In this case, I can integrate on both sides and obtain $x^2-y^2=c$ over $\mathbb{R}_+$ for some constant $c$. This together with $x(t)y(t)\to 1$ yields the fact that both $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are bounded, i.e., there is no such sequence $(t_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$.

---

**Additional information**:

For some reason, I also know $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{y}$ are in $L^2(\mathbb{R}_+,\mathbb{R})$, i.e.,
$$\int_0^\infty \dot{x}(t)^2+\dot{y}(t)^2\;dt<\infty.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differential equation is
$$
2x\dot{x}-2y\dot{y}=y\dot{x}-x\dot{y}\tag{1}
,
$$
where $xy\to 1$ as $t\to\infty.$
Let $1/y=x+\delta,$ where $\delta\to 0$  as $t\to\infty,$ so that on differentiating $y$ with respect to $t,$
$$\dot{y}=-y^2(\dot{x}+\dot{\delta})=-\dfrac{\dot{x}+\dot{\delta}}{\left(x+\delta\right)^2}\, .\tag{2}$$
Now assume that $x$ is unbounded and $x\to \infty$ as $t\to\infty,$
Then, on substituting for $1/y$  into the differential equation $(1),$ we get
$$
2x\dot{x}+\dfrac{2(\dot{x}+\dot{\delta})}{\left(x+\delta\right)^2}\dfrac{1}{x+\delta}=\dfrac{\dot{x}}{x+\delta}+\dfrac{x(\dot{x}+\dot{\delta})}{\left(x+\delta\right)^2}\,.
$$
Multiplying through by $\left(x+\delta\right)^3$ gives
$$ 2\dot{x}x\left(x+\delta\right)^3+2(\dot{x}+\dot{\delta})=\dot{x}\left(x+\delta\right)^2 +x(\dot{x}+\dot{\delta})\left(x+\delta\right)\,.$$
We have assumed that $x$ is unbounded, so that $x\to\infty$ as $t\to \infty.$
Then as $x\to\infty,\ y\to 0$ and $\delta\to 0$ as $t\to \infty.$
Neglecting $\delta$ compared with $x$ in the preceding equation gives
$$
2\dot{x}x^4+2(\dot{x}+\dot{\delta})=\dot{x}x^2+x^2(\dot{x}+\dot{\delta})\,,
$$
or, on collecting terms,
$$
2x^2\dot{x}(x^2-\tfrac{1}{2})=(\dot{x}+\dot{\delta})(x^2-2)\,.
$$
Since, by assumption $x^2\gg2>1/2,$ we get
$$
2x^4\dot{x}\approx x^2\dot{x}+\dot{\delta}x^2\quad\text{or}\quad 2x^2\dot{x}(x^2-1/2)\approx \dot{\delta}x^2\,,
$$
or finally, by assuming that $x$ is unbounded, we arrive at the relation
$$
2\dot{x}x^2\approx \dot{\delta}\,.\tag{3}
$$
This gives, on integration,
$$2x^3\approx 3\delta+\text{const}\, ,$$
which is a contradiction, because $x\to\infty\implies \delta\to\infty$ and  we require that $\delta\to 0$ as $t\to\infty.$
Therefore there is no such sequence, $(t_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}.$

**Edit**

The differential equation may be written as
$$
\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}\left(y^2\left(\frac{x^2}{y^2}-1\right)\right)=y^2\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)\,.
$$
Putting $z=x/y$ then gives
$$
\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}\left[y^2(z^2-1)\right]=y^2\frac{{\rm d}z}{{\rm d}t}\, ,
$$
or
$$
(z^2-1)\frac{{\rm d}y^2}{{\rm d}t}+y^2\frac{{\rm d}(z^2-1)}{{\rm d}t}=y^2\frac{{\rm d}z}{{\rm d}t}\, .
$$
On dividing by $y^2(z^2-1)$ we get
$$
\frac{{\rm d}y^2}{y^2}+\frac{{\rm d}(z^2-1)}{z^2-1}=\frac{{\rm d}z}{z^2-1}\, ,
$$
and on integration
$$
\log(y^2)+\log(z^2-1)=\log\sqrt{\frac{z-1}{z+1}}+\text{const}\, ,
$$
or
$$
\log\left((x^2-y^2)\sqrt{\frac{x+y\vphantom{Y^{p}}}{x-y}}\,\,\right)=\text{const}\, .
$$
Since the initial conditions are $x=x_{0}$ and $y=y_{0}$ at $t=0,$
we have
$$
\log\left((x^2-y^2)\sqrt{\frac{x+y\vphantom{Y^{p}}}{x-y}}\,\,\right)=\log\left((x_{0}^2-y_{0}^2)\sqrt{\frac{x_{0}+y_{0}\vphantom{Y^{p}}}{x_{0}-y_{0}}}\,\,\right)\, .\tag{1}
$$

If $x$ is unbounded we require $y\to 0$ with $xy \to 1$ as $t\to\infty.$
Then from $(1),$ as $x$ becomes large and $y$ approaches zero,
we obtain
$$
\log(x^2)=\text{const}\, ,
$$
which is a contradiction, so $x$ and $y$ cannot become unbounded if the asymptotic constraint $xy\to 1$ as $t\to\infty$ is to be satisfied.

@William, the OP, has noted that if $z(t)=1$ at some time $t,$ then $\dot{z}=0$ and $z(t)$ will be always $1.$

Comment: Just to ensure that the additional information gives $\dot{x}$ is square integrable, not bounded. Will this change any part of your proof?

Comment: If we have already arrived at $2\dot{x}x^2\approx \dot{\delta}$, can we directly obtain $2x^3\approx 3\delta+\text{const}$? This already yields a contradiction because $x\to\infty$ and $\delta\to 0$.

Comment: I had just noted that observation too. Are there any boundary conditions in the problem, other than the limit constraint $xy\to 1$ as $t\to\infty.$

Comment: No boundary condition, but there are initial conditions $x(0)=x_0$ and $y(0)=y_0$.

Comment: By writing the differential equation as $\frac{{\rm d}(x^2-y^2)}{{\rm d}t}=y^2\frac{{\rm d}(x/y)}{{\rm d}t},$ and integrating with respect to $t$ using the limiting and initial conditions, we get $x^2\approx \log(x^2),$ which is also a contradiction, so it appears that $x$ cannot be unbounded without violating the $xy\to 1$ as $t\to\infty$ constraint.

Comment: This idea seems better than what you wrote in the answer, it would be nice if you can briefly mention how you get $x^2\approx \log(x^2)$ by taking integration. Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: $x^2-y^2=\int_{0}^{t}y^2 \{d(x/y)/dt\}\,dt.$ Integrate by parts using the limit condition: 
$x^2-1/x^2=[y^2x/y]_{0}^{t}-\int_{0}^{t}(x/y)2y\dot{y}\, dt=
1-x_{0}y_{0}-2\int_{0}^{t}x\dot{y}\,dt.$
Putting $x\dot{y}=-\dot{x}y$ from differentiating the limit condition into the integral gives
$x^2-1/x^2=1-x_{0}y_{0}+2\int_{0}^{t}y\dot{x}\,dt.$
Making the crude approximation that $y=1/x$ over the integration gives
$x^2\approx 2\int_{0}^{t}\dot{x}/x\,dt,$
or $x^2\approx 2\log(x)=\log(x^2),$ ignoring the lower limit.
 Maybe the last integral can be improved.

Comment: Does $x(t)y(t)\to 1$ implies that the derivative of it converges to $0$? I guess it is not true in general?

Comment: Nice modification. Just without loss of generality, you may want to discuss if $z(t)=1$ at some time $t$, then $\dot{z}=0$ and $z(t)$ will be always $1$. Rigorously speaking, you cannot say $x(t)\to\infty$ because when arguing by contradiction, you only know $x(t_k)\to\infty$ and $y(t_k)\to 0$ along a sequence. Except for this sequence, you don't know whether $z(t)=1$ infinitely often or not. If $z(t)=1$ along another sequence, then dividing $z^2-1$ on both sides is not valid.

Comment: If we arrive at (1) by some means, is the scaffolding used to find it really necessary?  That is, is dividing by $z^2-1$ required?

Comment: It would be better if we don't need to divide $z^2-1$. In your revised answer, one needs to divide $z^2-1$ because one would like to do separation of variable?